# Typescript interface where key name has known prefix but full key is unknown

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define an interface in which the keys have a known prefix (`added_`, `removed_`) but the full key is unknown?

For example, a valid object might be:

```
{
   name: "",
   added_abc: [1,2,3],
   added_bcd: [2],
   removed_abcd: [4,5],
   removed_xyz: [],
}
```

I'd want to ensure an interface with:

```
interface myobject {
   name: string;
   added_*?: number[];
   removed_*?: number[];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When TypeScript 4.4 is released, you will be able to leverage [template string pattern literal index signatures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44512](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512), and then this will work:

```
// TS4.4+
interface MyObject {
  name: string;
  [k: `added_${string}`]: number[];
  [k: `removed_${string}`]: number[];
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
  name: "",
  added_abc: [1, 2, 3],
  added_bcd: [2],
  removed_abcd: [4, 5],
  removed_xyz: [],
} // okay

const myBadObject: MyObject = {
  name: "",
  added_abc: [1, 2, 3],
  addled_bcd: [2], // error!
}
```

Until then, there is no specific type in TypeScript which represents your requirements.  You can use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper functions with template literal types in TS4.1 to TS4.3, but such functions are more complicated:

```
// TS 4.1-4.3
const asMyObject = <T extends { name: string } & { [K in keyof T]:
  K extends `added_${string}` | `removed_${string}` ? number[] :
  K extends "name" ? string :
  never }>(t: T) => t;

const myObject2 = asMyObject({
  name: "",
  added_abc: [1, 2, 3],
  added_bcd: [2],
  removed_abcd: [4, 5],
  removed_xyz: [],
}); // okay

const myBadObject2 = asMyObject({
  name: "",
  added_abc: [1, 2, 3],
  addled_bcd: [2], // error!  
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210702&ssl=40&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbnOQG0BrBgAM4AExEQRAfQAkxZqxBsAvoIC6DEAFdq2aD1VcK-IVAjUA9gDcJMuS3Yr1lbbqj6uS0gHovyACoAysgALAB0wQDUpAjmIMzI1Fh4BGAMGDj4hMgAvCTcVLQMAERFADTcouJScNgIDDwAjKXIAEzNAMyq5RSVNrUi9S1d3KYW1tX99cHNAKzDFKNWNgAe6ABe9cOe0bHxiQBCohkpaUmZRLlkFAX0yCXdyL0TdbxNrR3zj2IANn0IA7whs0fMhoFBzFAAISkbYgwIhULtAC0OziRDgjHSySyuQAPH5QctICARIwSJQaLd5OxkEpkAAyck8ADSyFAyD4EHQ5hg-nU3FZECJEBJZOEYhssmpihUyAAPshBItxrZpcpBMgAPzOHR6VTIOgCwnE0l3G5FLVMeyKA35CDWKC0gB8AApUv4AJQ5J3IMBcVF7M4pFo5R6YoOEF1XCmFO5lCoS571N5tZCdB5PSSTQGfZU2Gr-KazXNmJZSVYbXhbD0cZAg8x8ODoUgBogHI7YsAh3IYrHnKP5SnFeM9ROSAvJ5qp9MJkS-KTZnhAuu+MEQyEUGE10hAA)

Comment: What an amazing feature. Thanks for sharing